# Error when declaring vector after malloc()

Tags: c++, pointers, malloc, stdvector

new here! I was experimenting with pointers and vectors and somehow ran into an error after this:

```
    p = (int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
    p[10] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++) std::cout << p[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
    std::vector<int> v(10);
```

This is the output I get:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
malloc.c:2401: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == initial_top (av) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= MINSIZE && prev_inuse (old_top) && ((unsigned long) old_end & (pagesize - 1)) == 0)' failed.
```

I know I'm wrongly assigning an element of p outside of the allocated memory, but I'm curious about why does the declaration of vector v fail after this. I also tried the same idea with smaller sizes for p (i.e. 5 instead of 10) and it didn't throw the error, which I find interesting as well. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, it's UB, so anything might happen. It doesn't make much sense to reason about it.. Probably writing out of bounds overwrites some part of memory that was somehow related to the vector.

Comment: Change compiler options, and maybe the code acts differently.  You will then see that this is a moving target that can keep changing, and thus reconsider whether it is worth any time spending on why the code behaves as it does.

Comment: [Documentation for that "UB" thing Churill mentioned](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)

Comment: What do you mean by "declaration fails"? And your subject is misleading - there is no `reserve()` in code shown.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Good to know there are things one just shouldn't try to reason about. I changed the subject as well, I originally thought it was failing at a reserve() but I took it out later.

Answer (score 2):

When the size of an array is 10, the maximum index is 9 and the loop must use `i < 10` instead of 11:

```
p = (int*)malloc(10*sizeof(int));
p[9] = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) std::cout << p[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

Comment: I do not think this is what OP asks about.